# Is given condition significantly impacting linear regression?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-regression, python, p-value, linear-model

In short: How to check in python if given condition is significantly impacting linear regression outcome compared to a reference? I have no background in statistics, so it's hard to figure everything myself.

For example let's say I'm supposed to check if various modifications of a concrete structure affect the performance.

I have a reference structure (with 3 steel bars) and structures with 4 and 5 bars. Also I have 5-bar structures with chromium and titanium.

The performance I investigate is obtained by calculating the intercept (Y0) of a linear fit of "goodness vs. length" diagram (see picture below).
[image]

I know what are the Y0's and slopes, but I have no idea how to check if adding steel bars or other metals SIGNIFICANTLY affects the Y0 compared to the reference.

In various blogs I've read that I have to replace categorical variables with dummy variables. But I have no background in statistics, so I have no idea how to proceed.

My code is:

```
import pandas as pd
ref = pd.DataFrame({"Length":[1,2,3],"Goodness":[1,2,3],"Category":["ref","ref","ref"]})
Df4bars = pd.DataFrame({"Length":[1,2,3],"Goodness":[4,5,6],"Category":["4bars","4bars","4bars"]})
Df5bars = pd.DataFrame({"Length":[1,2,3],"Goodness":[7,8,9],"Category":["5bars","5bars","5bars"]})
Df5barsCr = pd.DataFrame({"Length":[1,2,3],"Goodness":[3,5,7],"Category":["5barsCr","5barsCr","5barsCr"]})
Df5barsTi = pd.DataFrame({"Length":[1,2,3],"Goodness":[5,5,5],"Category":["5barsTi","5barsTi","5barsTi"]})
AllData = pd.concat([ref,Df4bars,Df5bars,Df5barsTi,Df5barsCr],ignore_index=True)
AllData = pd.get_dummies(AllData, columns = ['Category'])
```

And it would be nice to have an outcome looking for example like this:

```
4 bars - significant
5 bars - significant
5 bars+Ti - insignificant
5 bars+Cr - insignificant
```

Comment: use statsmodel package eg https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/examples/notebooks/generated/ols.html#OLS-with-dummy-variables

Comment: @seanv507 I can somewhat see the usefulness of this document, however I'm still quite confused. I really have no statistics knowledge, and every term is a rabbit hole of thousand definitions for me. Do you mean F-test is the answer to my needs?

Comment: no you would run the fit and in the summary see whether each coefficient (=4 bars significant etc) is marked as significant (P>|t| ) < 0.05 or whatever cutoff you decide to label as significant.  however, there are lots of gotchas so I would advise finding yourself a consultant if this actually has some importance to you.